# Constrain PEX code-under-test to a single method?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moles, pex

Can the code-under-test in PEX be constrained to a single method? I am aware you can constrain it to assemblies and classes, but what about members?

I am essentially trying to achieve 100% code coverage for the following method:

```
public virtual bool GetLastSymbol(string symbolHint, out string symbol)
{
    if (symbolHint == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("symbolHint");
    }

    IEnumerable<string> symbols;
    symbol = this.VariableHints.TryGetValue(symbolHint, out symbols) ? symbols.Last() : null;

    return symbol != null;
}
```

The following PUT achieves **12/15** code coverage, because I’m only testing for 1 of the possible 2 values it can return:

```
found = symbolManager.GetLastSymbol(symbolHint, out symbol);
PexAssert.IsFalse(found);
```

To achieve full coverage for this PUT, I need to change the object’s state so that the method hits both branches. I could satisfy this by using separate PUTs using a factory method to setup the different states, but this would leave me with 2 PUTs with incomplete code coverage, rather than 1 PUT with full coverage. I realise *in theory* the 2 PUTs would have a combined coverage of 100%, but I need that 100% figure *in practice* so I can setup CI properly.

So, to reach the other branch in the same PUT, I must append the following code to the above 2 lines:

```
symbolManager.CreateSymbol(symbolHint); // Ensure next call returns true.
found = symbolManager.GetLastSymbol(symbolHint, out symbol);
PexAssert.IsTrue(found);
```

Presumably the code coverage for the `GetLastSymbol` method is now 100%, but because I’ve introduced another method call to the type under test, the code coverage now drops to **20/29**.

How can I constrain a PUT to only measure code coverage for a single method? I realise I may have misunderstood this metric entirely, so please explain why if this is the case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'PEX API Reference' which comes installed with PEX was useful for solving this:

The Microsoft.Pex.Framework.Coverage namespace includes several filter attributes which can exclude various facets from effecting code coverage. The one I wanted was:

```
PexCoverageFilterMethodAttribute
```

Using this method I was able to remove the `CreateSymbol` method from the coverage report:

```
[PexCoverageFilterMethod(PexCoverageDomain.UserOrTestCode, "CreateVariable")]
```

This now increased my code coverage to **13/15**; higher than before, but still not the 100% I was expecting. Long story short, I discovered PEX was including the constructor in the coverage reports too...

```
[PexCoverageFilterMethod(PexCoverageDomain.UserOrTestCode, "ctor")]
```

I'm now receiving **13/13** for my code coverage. I'm a happy bunny :)